# "In the black" as complements

Tags: complements

> in the black idiom : making a profit : profitable

Can "in the black" be used as complements of "become"?

As you know, "at ease" can be used as "I feel at ease", "you look at ease".

Is "our country became in the black" or "our country seems in the black" grammatical?

Comment: **became**, no; **seems**, yes, though unlikely with "country" as subject.  Why "country"?   It makes a decent question a weird one. How could a country be turning a profit? Are you testing the grammaticality of absurd utterances, or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The country seems to be in black" is grammatical, and "The country seems in the black" would probably be accepted as a shortening of that.

"Becoming in the black" is questionable at best. If "in the black" has achieved full idiom status and has no compositional nature, then it's acceptable. But if it retains its nature as a prepositional phrase, then it doesn't work. So "becoming out of sorts" works better than "becoming in the black", because the "out" has less of a prepositional compositional nature in "out of sorts" than "in" does in "in the black".

While prepositional phrases act like adjectives in many ways, they aren't generally states that one can "become". For instance, "I am becoming in the house" or "I am becoming near the store" sound off. There are other phrasings, such as "getting to be in the black" or "on their way to being in the black" that are more idiomatic.